# Python transpose, column name are inside the dataframe records

Tags: python, csv, pandas, transpose

I'm quite sure that I'm missing something very elementary here, but I didn't really found what i was looking for in the pandas documentation.

I download a ForEx data-frame , and want to save it, but before I do that, I have to format it to a 8 columns/X rows, matrix/data-frame/vector (as many rows as needed). I have it as a line with every record having his column name next to it. (I can save it in .CSV)

My powers here are .transpose, which alone isn't doing the trick.

I already succeded with this once, but I seems to have forgotten to save the code and it was a while back.... But thanks to this I can show you an older csv I read in to python, and show how I want to format it.

(column names: Index(not really a column, it is just the index),close,date,high,low,open,close,qouteVolume,volume,weightedAvarage)

[image]
[image]

```
    source_df = get_ForEx_data(**params)
list(source_df )
list(TransposedData)
TransposedData = source_df .transpose()
```

Edit: (function that gets the data from the internet)

```
def get_poloinex_data(s, a, b, c):

import requests
from pandas import DataFrame
from io import StringIO

url = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData'

url += '&currencyPair=' + s #USDT a dollár
url += '&start=' + a
url += '&end=' + b
url += '&period=' + c

csv = requests.get(url)

if csv.ok:
    return DataFrame.from_csv(StringIO(csv.text), sep=',') #Separátor itt!
else:
    return None
```

The data I get using this is like this in python:

```
Columns: [high:1.85, low:0.50000021, open:1.65, close:1.85, volume:144.42819254, quoteVolume:84.01638508, weightedAverage:1.71904792}, {"date":1439020800, high:1.7, low:1.40000001, open:1.7, close:1.40000001, volume:129.57577588, quoteVolume:92.52305316, weightedAverage:1.40047016}, {"date":1439035200, high:1.40000001, low:1.40000001.1, open:1.40000001, close:1.40000001.1, volume:0, quoteVolume:0, weightedAverage:1.40000001}, {"date":1439049600, high:1.40000001.1, low:1.40000001.2, open:1.40000001.1, close:1.40000001.2, volume:0.1, quoteVolume:0.1, weightedAverage:1.40000001}.1, {"date":....
```

what I looking for is like this:

```
              close                 date       high        low       open  \
0      1.850000  2015-08-08 04:00:00   1.850000   0.500000   1.650000   
1      1.400000  2015-08-08 08:00:00   1.700000   1.400000   1.700000   
2      1.400000  2015-08-08 12:00:00   1.400000   1.400000   1.400000   
3      1.400000  2015-08-08 16:00:00   1.400000   1.400000   1.400000
```

and so on with the remaining columns

Comment: What is `get_ForEx_data()`? Is this a method you created that runs some type of API to download data? Please show actual source data (not as a screenshot but posted text) before any pandas work.

Comment: Yes, sorry I mistyped ForEx, I use this to get cryptocurrency data from poloinex (I hav e two of these, they are the same only the URL is different) will edit in a moment (edit: I can't post code in to comments? edit2: ohh it was just too long, sorry Ctrl+K if anyone interested)

Comment: Can we see the data of the returned request? Just dump a few lines and then code format `{}` in toolbar.

Comment: Sorry I tried to add the requested information in comment, but at the end I decided to add it to the main question (there were problems with the character limit)

Comment: Your API request is a json format and pandas has great json tools. However this json is not valid as string identifiers must be in quotes and only *date* is. Plus the outer *Columns* must be enclosed in a container. Either you removed it in post here or its source is invalid.

Comment: So, I should convert it to string, add '' (qoutes) to the column names and try to work on it after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Parfait already stated, your data is in JSON format, not CSV. Therefore use pandas's `read_json` function instead of `from_csv`.

Import the whole pandas module:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Transform the JSON data to a DataFrame:

```
if csv.ok:
    return pd.read_json(StringIO(csv.text))
else:
    return None
```

This will return a DataFrame of exactly your desired format:

```
        close                date      high       low      open  quoteVolume
0    0.000073 2015-08-08 08:00:00  0.000073  0.000073  0.000073     0.000000   
1    0.000073 2015-08-08 08:05:00  0.000073  0.000073  0.000073     0.000000   
2    0.000073 2015-08-08 08:10:00  0.000073  0.000073  0.000073     0.000000
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the slow response time, but I can't work on this while im at work. It works, and saves the data just the way i need it, I spent a few minutes trying to give it different arguments, but turned out the basic one handels it just right